# How to get_queried_object of another post by id to get parents of parent post?

Tags: wordpress

I want to get_queried_object of parent to see does he have any parents. How can i get it?
I think that it should be something like this

```
$parent_id_of_current_category->get_queried_object()->parent;
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be like this: `$parent_id_of_current_category = get_queried_object()->parent;`?

Comment: @imhvost it gives me parent id of current category, but i want to get parent id of parent category

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_term_by`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/):

```php
$father_term_id = get_queried_object()->parent;

$grandfather_term_id = get_term_by( 'term_taxonomy_id', $father_term_id )->parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = get_queried_object_id();
$ancestors = get_ancestors($id,'product_cat');
```

Here is the solution, to get all parent of post/taxonomy/page and so on. Just replace 'product_cat' with what you need